# Jade conditional - Unexpected else without if

Tags: node.js, pug

```
block main
  h2.content-heading My profile
  .block
    .block-content.block-content-full
      a.block.block-link-hover2(href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-fadein" type="button")
        .block-header
            //- h3.block-title.text-center Author of the Month
        div(class="block-content block-content-full text-center bg-image" style=(account.backgroundImage))
          div
            img.img-avatar.img-avatar96.img-avatar-thumb(src=(account.avatar), alt='')
          .h5.text-white.push-15-t.push-5 #{account.displayname}
        .block-content
          .row.items-push.text-center
            .col-xs-6.col-xs-offset-3
              .push-5
            if account.premium
                i.fa.fa-bolt.fa-2x(style="color: #FF9800;")
              .h5.font-w300.text-muted Premium member
            else 
                i.fa.fa-thumbs-up.fa-2x(style="color: #3c3c3c;")
              .h5.font-w300.text-muted Free user
```

The error:

```
Unexpected else without if
```

I'm passing `account.premium` as false through res.render. Everything else under the account object is working fine, apart from this if/else block.

Comment: Entire, full code pl0x.

Comment: @A.Abramov Updated with the best I could do.

Comment: @A.Abramov Nailed it on the head. I never knew Jade was so sensitive to white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is important.

**Working code:**

`if account.premium
  i.fa.fa-bolt.fa-2x(style="color: #FF9800;")
  .h5.font-w300.text-muted Premium member
else 
  i.fa.fa-thumbs-up.fa-2x(style="color: #3c3c3c;")
  .h5.font-w300.text-muted Free user`

Comment: This is literally the solution i gave you in the comment. Usually, it's more acceptable to wait for me to post it. Meh, i won't bug about the reputation this time, since i deleted the comment - but you should know that's what acceptable for the next time.